# How to pass data to component directly from click, or click handler without proxy object?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, modal-dialog

I have a table of objects, each row has an edit pencil icon. I have an edit dialog component, which takes an object and allows edit, problem is, how do I hook up the pencil icon, launch the dialog with that object?

```
<tr v-for="obj in objs" :key="obj.id">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="obj.id" number>
  </td>

  <td class="text-left">{{obj.name}}</td>
  <td class="text-left">{{obj.description}}</td>

  <!-- buttons -->
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-unstyled"
              @click="???"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#edit-dlg">
        <fa-icon icon="pencil-alt" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
<edit-student-dialog id="edit-dlg" :student="???" />
```

I know I can just make a `selectedItem` in the parent, and bind the child dialog components prop to it, but I do not like that solution especially since I am cloning the object again in the dialog. It seems unnecessary. I just want to pass the object directly to the dialog component without a proxy.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: I guess if you don't want to use props, or the sync modifier, then vuex.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what is the sync modifier?

Comment: [This is the sync modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)